# Estimate eps value in DBSCAN using KNN algorithm

Tags: python, algorithms, k-nn, dbscan

I would like to estimate the best eps value for the DBSCAN algorithm on [this](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c6dd1bc7e68b6c248dfe44c59277ddfc/CURE-complete.csv) dataset by following this set of rules:

1. Set a minPts: 10
2. Compute the reachability distance of the 10-th nearest neighbour for each data-point.
3. Sort the set of reachability distances and plot to get the elbow of the diagram (best eps value).

This is the first part of my code where I load the dataset:

```
import csv
import sys
import os
from os.path import join
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def load_data(file_path, file_name):
   with open(join(file_path, file_name)) as csv_file:
       data_file = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
       temp1 = next(data_file)
       n_samples = int(temp1[0])
       print("n_samples=")
       print(n_samples)
       n_features = int(temp1[1])
       temp2 = next(data_file)
       feature_names = np.array(temp2[:n_features])

       data_list = [iter for iter in data_file]
               
       data = np.asarray(data_list, dtype=np.float64)                  
       
   return(data,feature_names,n_samples,n_features)

# --- Main program ---

file_path="Datasets/"    
file_name3="CURE-complete.csv"    
data3,feature_names3,n_samples3,n_features3 = load_data(file_path, file_name3)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=1)
ax.set_title('Dataset n. 3 of data points')
ax.set_xlabel(feature_names3[0])
ax.set_ylabel(feature_names3[1])
plt.plot(data3[:,0], data3[:,1], '.', markersize=1.2, markeredgecolor = 'blue')
plt.show()
```

This is where I compute the KNN-algorithm with ns (minpts) = 10.

```
ns = 10 #minpts
nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=ns).fit(data3)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(data3)
distanceDec = sorted(distances[:,ns-1], reverse=True)
plt.plot(list(range(1,len(distanceDec)+1)), distanceDec)
```

This is the resulting diagram, which seems unusual considering the range of values:
[image]

How can I improve my algorithm? As you can see in the following [page](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/wiki.php?id_contents=7940#method-for-determining-the-optimal-eps-value), the plot (in my case it's reversed), should be different.

From what I understood the best eps value should be in the corner above 2.2, right?